# Business Objects ver 3 Alternate Row/Column Colors not active

Tags: business-objects

I am converting reports from version 2 to version 3.  When I select the vertical table in the report, the properties box appears but any change I make is not reflected in the table. If I change any attributes at the column or cell level however, the changes are taken.  The problem is that some attributes like alternate row coloring are not available at the column level.

Answer (score 0):

Are you pressing enter after making the change?  It sounds like a silly question, but I know failing to press enter after changing a universe for a query source won't be saved by the editor and it immediately reverts to the original value.